# How to define a private member and use it in the class itself using es6 'Class' syntax

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

It's really straightforward for me to use private members and use those members inside the class with ECMAScript5, however I don't understand how to get this thing worked with ECMAScript6 using class syntax.

In my code I've tried declaring a property inside constructor function and used the function in a method, but it gets undefined.

```
class Employee {
    constructor(name, empId, workedHours, payment) {
        var discount = 0.28;    
        this.name = name;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.workedHours = workedHours;
        this.payment = payment;
    }

    monthlyWage() {
        return (this.workedHours * this.payment) + (this.workedHours * discount);
    }
}
emp1 = new Employee('CooreyMShapher', 12, 89, 900);
```

So, Is there any way I can use this `discount` variable inside every method in the class without defining it as an object attribute?

Comment: "*It's really straightforward for me to use private members and use those members inside the class with ECMAScript5*" - how exactly are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put the whole class in an IIFE, and define `discount` inside, to ensure that `discount` is viewable to the `Employee` class, but not by anything outside:

```js
const Employee = (() => {
  const discount = 0.28;
  return class Employee{
    constructor(name, empId, workedHours, payment){

      this.name = name;
      this.empId = empId;
      this.workedHours = workedHours;
      this.payment = payment;
    }

    monthlyWage(){
      return (this.workedHours * this.payment) + (this.workedHours * discount);
    }
  }
})();
const emp1 = new Employee('CooreyMShapher', 12, 89, 900);
console.log(emp1.monthlyWage());
```

Note that there's currently a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features) to make this a lot nicer-looking - you may, in the future, be able to use `#` before a class field to indicate that only the class itself may see the variable:

```
class Employee{
  static #discount = 0.28;
  constructor(name, empId, workedHours, payment){
    this.name = name;
    this.empId = empId;
    this.workedHours = workedHours;
    this.payment = payment;
  }

  monthlyWage(){
    return (this.workedHours * this.payment) + (this.workedHours * Employee.#discount);
  }
}
```